# ggplot2 with ablines only

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am following an example from the [ggplot documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html)

This is the code:

```
library(plyr)
coefs <- ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), function(df) {
  m <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=df)
  data.frame(a = coef(m)[1], b = coef(m)[2])
})

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg), . ~ cyl) + geom_point()
p + geom_abline(data=coefs, aes(intercept=a, slope=b))
```

However, I would like the same graphic with the 'ablines' only! No dots!
Trying:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg), . ~ cyl)
p + geom_abline(data=coefs, aes(intercept=a, slope=b))
```

Gives me an error: 'argument "env" is missing, with no default'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `geom_blank()` which will calculate limits (et al) but then let you just use `geom_abline`:

```
p + geom_blank() + geom_abline(data=coefs, aes(intercept=a, slope=b))
```

[image]